# Nix desktop files

Tags: .desktop, nix

When I install a GUI application using nix, I see desktop files end inside `~/.nix-profile` directory, e.g:

`~/.nix-profile/share/applications/firefox.desktop`

However, my desktop expect that files to be in `/user/share/applications` in order to be able to create desktop icons for them.

Is there any way to tell nix to symlink desktop files to `/user/share/applications` so I don't have to do it manually?

Thanks

Comment: A workaround might be to set the some of the environment variables defined by the [spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-latest.html#paths).

Comment: You tagged your question with [nixos] but do you actually use NixOS or just the Nix package manager on another distribution? And what is your desktop environment?

Comment: Thanks @olejorgenb. That's definitely the good direction

Comment: Hey @Zimmi48 No, I'm not in NixOs, but I thought the question is anyway related and people knowing about NixOs could bring some light. I'm using Nix in Qubes OS with Xfce, so my question was indeed simplified because maybe I will need to adapt Qubes script which reads from within the VM with Nix installed. But knowing the general behavior should be enough, and then if something in Qubes is not standardized I should report there.

Comment: In that case, the nixos tag is really not necessary because people following it are most likely to follow the nix tag as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Supposing that you are using a distribution other than NixOS, then yes you can expect your desktop environment to be looking for your applications in `/usr/share/applications` while those installed with Nix are actually in `~/.nix-profile/share/applications`.

Instead of creating a symlink from `/usr/share/applications` you should rather tell you desktop where to look. You should be able to do so by adding the following to your `~/.profile`:

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=$HOME/.nix-profile/share:$HOME/.share:"${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/}"
```

So your desktop will be looking for applications both in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.nix-profile/share/applications`, with a priority given to the applications installed with Nix.

For more info, https://nixos.org/wiki/KDE#Using_KDE_outside_NixOS

Comment: I think that this is the right answer. I will not need to check how all of this works within QubesOS.

Comment: I think this is the right way. However, I don't understand why it is so complex. `export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$HOME/.nix-profile/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS}"` is enough for me.

Comment: Your simplified command corresponds to my original answer. The command has just been made more fail-proof by an editor for the case where `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` does not exist. I don't know why `$HOME/.share` was added to the list though.

Comment: Shouldn't `$HOME/.share` be `$HOME/.local/share` instead?

Comment: I use KDE Plasma on Arch Linux. `.profile` doesn't work, but `.xsessionrc` works. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471327/whats-the-right-way-to-add-directories-to-xdg-data-dirs/531664#531664

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Debian + bspwm (neither of the proposed commands in `.profile` (but I do set there many other environment variables that do work). Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: For globally installed apps, you need to also add: `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/share`.

Comment: @GerardBosch, I think the editor indeed meant `$HOME/.local/share`. There is no `$HOME/.share` defined by freedesktop.org. Unfortunately, I can't currently edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` in `.profile`, I could not log in with Ubuntu Gnome 16.10.

Instead, I solved it with symlinks. The command below finds all links in `.nix-profile/share/applications` and links them into `.local/share/applications`. Replace `teodorlu` with your username.

```
find ~/nix-profile/share/applications -type l -exec ln -s /home/teodorlu/{} ~/.local/share/applications \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the current top answer does not satisfy many systems, including my archcraft one, here is my variation:
Create `etc/profile.d/nix-xdg-data-dirs.sh` with content:

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=${HOME}/.nix-profile/share:${HOME}/.share:"${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/}"
```

PS: Sry, too little reputation for commenting, hence new answer.