# What's the right way to add directories to XDG_DATA_DIRS?

Tags: directory-structure, xdg, xdg-open

I've installed some app under `/opt/myapp`, which has a `/opt/myapp/share` directory. As I finish installing, it tells me:

```
Note that '/opt/myapp/share' is not in the search path
set by the XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_DATA_DIRS
environment variables, so applications may not
be able to find it until you set them. The
directories currently searched are:

- /usr/share/gnome
- /home/joeuser/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share
- /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share
- /usr/local/share
- /usr/share
```

What's the right way to add directories to that list - system-wide and as a single user?

Answer (score 17):

The [German ubuntuusers wiki has a nice list](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Umgebungsvariable/Dateien/#Environment-einzelner-oder-aller-Benutzer) of files and directories that can be used for that purpose.

### Setting it globally

From my research, appending to that environment variable globally is not trivial, but here are some pointers:

- If you want to overide the existing value, `/etc/environment` is the easiest way
- Depending on the system configuration `/etc/profile` might also be a good way, because you it is executed by the shell
- Other files to try might be `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/*` and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`

### Setting it per-user

- `$HOME/.profile` (or `$HOME/.zprofile` for zsh users) is suggested in multiple places, however adding the line `XDG_DATA_DIRS="$HOME/.local/xdg:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"` in there rendered my desktop completely non-functional upon login
- The way that worked for me was to create `$HOME/.xsessionrc` and put the line `export XDG_DATA_DIRS="$HOME/.local/xdg:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"` in there. Of course, you have to replace `$HOME/.local/xdg` by the directory you want to add. Please also note that this will only set the variable for graphical applications, not for the shell (so your value won't be mentioned in `echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS`), but that should not be a problem.

### Recommendation

Just execute this line and log in again, and it should work:

```
echo export 'XDG_DATA_DIRS="/opt/myapp/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"' >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

If for whatever reason your system is nonfunctional after that, enter [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), go into the root shell and type `rm /home/<username>/.xsessionrc` and then `reboot` to get back into your system.

Comment: Note that I switched to Arch now, which doesn't support `xsessionrc` by default (looks like it's read by the login manager) and also doesn't seem to set XDG_DATA_DIRS to a default value, so i am looking into moving it.

Comment: If you are using Wayland, you can do `XDG_DATA_DIRS=<your_dir>:$XDG_DATA_DIRS` in `~/.config/environment.d/envvars.conf` for per-user config.

Comment: I set all these kinds of variables in my `.zshenv` now as that is my default shell

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about system wide.. but as a single user (which is accessible sytem-wide) I include this line in my `~/.profile` file.

`XDG_DATA_DIRS="/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"`

And you can adapt that to meet your own needs.